# ElasticSearch - Sequential keyword/phrase searching

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to search for a keyword that happens after another keyword or phrase?

I've been trying to use span_near with slop of 10000000 while marked in_order=true, but it doesn't like phrases... otherwise it works with keywords

The closest solution I could come up with is the following:

```
            foreach($arrKeywords[$i] as $strKeyword)
            {
                $arrClauses[] = ['span_term' => ['transcript' => '"'.$strKeyword.'"']];
            }

            $objQuery->query->bool->should[]->span_near = [
                'clauses' => $arrClauses,
                'slop' => 100000000,
                'in_order' => true
            ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason to not to use the following?

```
"query": {
    "match_phrase": {
        "title": {
            "query": "YOUR KEYWORD OR PHRASE + KEYWORD",
            "slop":  1 # change this as you wish
        }
    }
}
```

Though above query may relax the phrase condition you want, then you can combine two queries with bool query; one of them is above and the other one is simple match_phrase with *slop=0* searching you keyword/phrase.

Comment: Self-answer: Slop does not guarantee order, I guess. This might be the reason for you to choose span queries.

Comment: slop would go before the given keyword to find potential other keywords. I've played around with query_string with phrase/wildcards like: ' "keyword1*keyword2" '

I'm trying to find only keyword2 AFTER the fact of keyword1